# electron setWindowOpenHandler is not a function

Tags: typescript, electron

I created an Electron-App for my web-app, which uses SAML. I want to allow the saml window to show up.

So I used the BrowserWindow.WebContents.setWindowOpenHandler function.

I first tried it, where the window object is being instanciated with a new BrowserWindow. That didn't work. I found on GitHub a new method, using the event "web-contents-created"

```
//Erlaube SAML Authentifizierung, andere Seiten werden blockiert
app.on("web-contents-created", (createEvent, contents) => {
  contents.setWindowOpenHandler(({url}) => {
    if(url.startsWith("https://login.microsoftonline.com/")) {
      return {action: 'allow'};
    }
    else return {action: 'deny'};
  });
});
```

That didn't word either, I always get the same error messages:
[image: The error message after I start the application]

I'm using TypeScript and it's valid code.
I'm using Electron 17.1.2

Anyone knows why and how?

Comment: really weird.
In the first case, I think the webcontents only starts existing after you've navigated it to a URL if I remember correctly, so you might want to try that. It's weird though that web-contents-created is firing but contents is null. Can you check actually. Is the content param null or does that function just not exist? In which case I'd wonder if you're still somehow on an old electron version

Comment: I had the exact same issue and I couldn't figure out what is wrong.
When I did 
`console.log(Object.keys(mainWindow.webContents).sort().join('\n'))` — there is indeed no `setWindowOpenHandler`, but there was `_windowOpenHandler`, so assigning a value to it worked:
`mainWindow.webContents._windowOpenHandler = () => { ... }` — Although, it's probably not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in maindwindow

```
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
if (url.startsWith('https://www*')) {
  return {
    action: 'allow',
    overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
      width: 624,
      height: 428,
    },
  };
} else {
  console.log("Blocked by 'setWindowOpenHandler'");
  return { action: 'deny' };
}
```

});